# Count item frequency

Tags: algorithm, delphi, delphi-2009

Hi I'm using Delphi and I have a StringList with this items:

```
45
A15
015
A15
A15
45
```

I want to process it and make a second stringlist that will have 
the number of appearance of each element:

```
45 [2]
015 [1]
A15 [3]
```

How can I do this with Delphi?

Comment: I wish I had so cool homework when I was a kid.
This is for fun.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a dictionary:

```
Frequencies := TDictionary <String, Integer>.Create;
try
  // Count frequencies
  for Str in StringList do
    begin
    if Frequencies.ContainsKey (Str) then
      Frequencies [Str] := Frequencies [Str] + 1
    else
      Frequencies.Add (Str, 1);
    end; 

   // Output results to console
   for Str in Frequencies.Keys do
     WriteLn (Str + ': ' + IntToStr (Frequencies [Str]));
finally
  FreeAndNil (Frequencies);
end;
```

The only problem might be that the order in which the results appear is completely random and dependes on the inner working of the hash map.

Thanks to [daemon_x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532231/daemon-x) for the full unit code:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils, Classes, Generics.Collections;

var Str: String;
    StringList: TStrings;
    Frequencies: TDictionary <String, Integer>;

begin
  StringList := TStringList.Create;

  StringList.Add('45');
  StringList.Add('A15');
  StringList.Add('015');
  StringList.Add('A15');
  StringList.Add('A15');
  StringList.Add('45');

  Frequencies := TDictionary <String, Integer>.Create;

  try
  // Count frequencies
  for Str in StringList do
    begin
      if Frequencies.ContainsKey (Str) then
        Frequencies [Str] := Frequencies [Str] + 1
      else
        Frequencies.Add (Str, 1);
    end;

   // Output results to console
   for Str in Frequencies.Keys do
     WriteLn (Str + ': ' + IntToStr (Frequencies [Str]));

finally
  StringList.Free;
  FreeAndNil(Frequencies);
end;

end.
```

Comment: @downvoter: could you please explain your reasons? Downvoting without a reason does not help anyone and is not very fair either IMHO.

Comment: @Smasher - I was the downvoter because there were some issues in TDictionary in D2009. But I hope that OP has update for it so I've edited your answer to take it back. Of course it's a good and fast solution but as I remember adding items to the TDictionary in D2009 took a long time without update.

Comment: @smasher.
Thank you for your help. I cant find the Dictionary component!
How can I use this with Delphi 2009?

Comment: Just add `Generics.Collections` to your uses list.

Comment: @smasher 

`code`
uses ..., Generics.Collections;

type
  Frequencies = TDictionary<String, integer>;

   try
    // Count frequencies
    for Str IN FL do  //Left side cannot be assigned to   
      begin
      if Frequencies.ContainsKey(Str) then //expression expected
        Frequencies[Str]:= Frequencies[Str] + 1
      else
        Frequencies.Add(Str, 1);
      end;

     // Output results to console
     for Str in Frequencies.Keys do
       WriteLn (Str + ': ' + IntToStr(Frequencies[Str]));
  finally
    FreeAndNil (Frequencies);
  end;
`code`

I get many errors

Comment: @Kabamaru - but as I mentioned be sure you have installed updates (from [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/reg/delphi)) otherwise this solution will be quite slow (I'm talking about 1000 more records).

Comment: @Smasher - you're welcome; but IMHO the most important are those updates; I remember that I've had a lot of troubles with TDictionary without them. Anyway congrats to your 5k :)

Answer (score 3):

I coded this on my head as I don't have Delphi installed as of now. Let me know how it works for you.
Stringlist1 is the original list with the items, stringlist2 is empty and will be used to store what you want.

```
for i := 0 to stringlist1.Count - 1 do
begin
    if (stringlist2.Values[stringlist1[i]] = '') then
        stringlist2.Values[stringlist1[i]] := '1'
    else
        stringlist2.Values[stringlist1[i]] :=
            IntToStr(StrToInt(stringlist2.Values[stringlist1[i]]) + 1);
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Sort the original list,

   ```
   list1.sort;
   ```
2. create a new list

   ```
   list2:=TStringList.Create;
   ```
3. iterate over the sorted list to count every different item
   and store the a count in the objects field of the resulting list (or if you don't use it already, just typecast the count into a pointer and store it as the object).

   ```
   previtem:=list1[0];
   count:=1;
   for i:=1 to list1.count-1 do
    begin
     if list1[i]=previtem then 
       inc(count)
     else
      begin
       list2.addObject(previtem,pointer(count));
       previtem:=list1[i];
       count:=1;
      end;
    end;
   list2.addObject(previtem,pointer(count));
   ```

finally, iterate again to add the count to the string

```
  for i:=0 to list2.count-1 do
    list2.items[i]:=list2[i]+' ['+inttostr(list2.objects[i])+']';
```